# Enumerate splitted by pages does not work with \restoregeometry or \afterpage

Tags: header-footer, enumerate, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I have a document used for worksheets.
When I use an enumerate and it flows from one page to the other, the pagestyle of the second page (`\pagestyle{fancy}`) does not apply, and instead, I am left with an header the size of the style of the first page.

However, since I am using:

```
\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
```

The second page should have an header size corresponding to the \pagestyle{fancy}.

However, if I stop the enumerate, the problem keeps happening.
The headers are only correct if I use `\newpage`, and then use `\begin{enumerate}[resume]`.

This only happens with enumerate. With text, the second page has the correct pagestyle.
Why is this happening? Thanks for all the help.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Third item
    \item Another item
    \item Yet another item
    \item A brand new (same) item
    \item Is this an item?
    \item Yes it is
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \item Third item
    \item Another item
    \item Yet another item
    \item A brand new (same) item
\end{enumerate}

\newpage % or \pagebreak

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item Is this an item?
    \item Yes it is
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: Here is the link for the full code: https://www.coderstool.com/cs/79b6Jt

Comment: please don't use external links, make an example and add it to the question.

Comment: `\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}`  is a very weird construct (`\afterpage` is already pretty weird)  where do you expect that `\restoregeometry` to execute, there is no documented group, it could appear absolutely anywhere, wherever the current group happens to end (such as after the enumerate)

Comment: unless you are changing the text width, you can usually accomodate the first page differences without using `\afterpage` or `\restoregeometry` (and I wrote `\afterpage` and can say with some confidence that `\afterpage{\aftergroup` has never been tested and will basically do some undefined behaviour depending on what context tex is in at a page break.)

Comment: It is easier to overlap margins than change them, especially for a single page.